# C++ Trapezoidal Integration Function Returning Negative Numbers when it shouldn't

Tags: c++

I am using the following function written in C++, whose purpose is to take the integral of one array of data (y) with respect to another (x)

```
// Define function to perform numerical integration by the trapezoidal rule
double trapz (double xptr[], double yptr[], int Npoints)
{
    // The trapzDiagFile object and associated output file are how I monitor what data the for loop actually sees.
    std::ofstream trapzDiagFile;
    trapzDiagFile.open("trapzDiagFile.txt",std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);

    double buffer = 0.0;
    for (int n = 0; n < (Npoints - 1); n++)
    {
        buffer += 0.5 * (yptr[n+1] + yptr[n]) * (xptr[n+1] - xptr[n]);
        trapzDiagFile << xptr[n] << "," << yptr[n] << std::endl;
    }

    trapzDiagFile.close();
    return buffer;
}
```

I validated this function for the simple case where x contains 100 uniformly spaced points from 0 to 1, and `y = x^2`, and it returned `0.33334`, as it should.
But when I use it for a different data set, it returns `-3.431`, which makes absolutely no sense. If you look in the attached image file, the integral I am referring to is the area under the curve between the dashed vertical lines.
It's definitely a positive number.
Moreover, I used the native trapz command in MATLAB on the same set of numbers and that returned 1.4376.
In addition, I translated the above C++ trapz function into MATLAB, line for line as closely as possible, and again got `1.4376`.
I feel like there's something C++ related I'm not seeing here. If it is relevant, I am using minGW-w64.

Apologies for the vagueness of this post. If I knew more about what kind of issue I am seeing, it would be easier to be concise about it.

Plot of the dataset for which the trapz function (my homemade C++ version) returns -3.431:

[image]

Comment: How are you reading in your data points for the c++ application?

Comment: The short version is that they are generated in other functions within my source file. I have another function, called calculateSlowingEfficiency, which generates an array of 500 uniformly spaced points from 1 to 150, and then uses another function, called calculateFinalVelocity, to get an array of 500 points. I select a certain range of the 500 data points, and allocate space for these particular points using the "new double[n]" command where n is type const int. I pass the pointers (xptr,yptr) to these shorter arrays to my trapz function from within the function 
calcualteFinalVelocity.

Comment: Here is a dropbox link to the particular data I have the issue with, in csv format.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qw0f0u5h3i6cdlu/trapzWeirdData.txt?dl=0

Comment: You need to stick a print statement in the loop that prints the x and y values for n and n+1.  I don't think there is anything wrong with the function - I think it is the data you are passing to the function.

Comment: Did you check that xptr is sorted in accending order? Also perhaps the data drops below the yaxis in which case the answer will be negative. If you want the area between the graph and yaxis you will need to identify when data crosses the yaxis and calculate it piecewise. Otherwise this function should aproximate 0 when evaluating a function like sine/cosine.

Comment: The file I linked above is a copy of data that was streamed out by the trapz function (I removed all lines related to that ofstream object in the code in my  original post for brevity). The data you see in that file is the data that trapz saw locally. I checked, and it's the same data I have in MATLAB when I run my translated version.

Comment: [The function you show works correctly with the data you show](http://rextester.com/WWYMT29681). To the extent there is a problem, it must needs lie elsewhere.

Comment: @zekian I am sure that the xptr is in ascending order, as shown in the linked text file. To be clear, I got the data in that file with the following line of code: 
trapzDiagFile << xptr[n] << "," << yptr[n] << std::endl;
where trapzDiagFile is an ofstream object. Thus, the data is definitely in ascending order.
Also, in regards to the data crossing the y-axis, it doesn't. Take a look at the plot I included with the original post. To clarify, I am not trying to make trapz only return positive numbers. I am trying to understand why it returned a negative number when it shouldn't have.

Comment: Please print the data that the loop is using, rather than the file you are parsing.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik Thank you!! That is good to know. I tried creating my data in my source file as vector objects, to more closely follow how you implemented the data storage, but trapz returned the same result of -3.431. My sense is that this doesn't appear to be a C++ issue. Do you have any suggestions on what to try next?

Comment: @zekian. This is where that file comes from. It is what is seen by the loop.

double trapz (double xptr[], double yptr[], int Npoints)
{
 double buffer = 0.0;
 std::ofstream trapzDiagFile;
 trapzDiagFile.open("trapzDiagFile.txt",std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);
 for (int n = 0; n < (Npoints - 1); n++)
 {
  buffer += 0.5 * (yptr[n+1] + yptr[n]) * (xptr[n+1] - xptr[n]);
  std::cout << xptr[n] << "," << xptr[n+1] << "," << yptr[n] << "," << yptr[n+1] << std::endl;
  trapzDiagFile << xptr[n] << "," << yptr[n] << std::endl;
 }
 trapzDiagFile.close();
 return buffer;
}

Comment: I edited the code in the original post to show how I obtained the file I shared the link to.

Comment: What is the value of xptr[Npoints-1]  and yptr[Npoints-1]?

Comment: For the data I passed to trapz, xptr[Npoints-1] = 0, yptr[Npoints-1] = 0. Good catch! I decreased the value of Npoints I passed by 1, and now trapz returns 1.4287 like it should. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the value of xptr[Npoints - 1]. It may be less than xptr[Npoints - 2], and was not included in the values that you output.